# Is there any given explanation for planet Mira's weirdness?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

In Xenoblade Chronicles X, a human colony ship crash lands on planet Mira. Most of the game is spent trying to find a portion of the ship (the Lifehold) which detached from the rest during the landing, which contains the stored consciousnesses of all the ship's residents. Throughout the game many mysteries about the planet are discovered - it gives all the different alien beings who live on it the ability to understand and communicate with each other, it somehow teleported some alien races to itself, it seems to be surrounded by a space-time anomaly that prevents anyone leaving it (either via spaceflight or time travel), and at the end of the game you discover it is somehow maintaining the stored consciousnesses from the Lifehold, despite the computer banks that are meant to be doing so having been totally destroyed.

Is any explanation for any of these behaviours ever given, either in game or out of game? Or should we just chalk it all up as an unexplained mystery?